# Component state persists after unmounting?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following code:

```
function Middle() {
    const [show, setShow]=useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>setShow(v=>!v)}>MIDDLE</button>
            <Bottom visible={show}/>
        </div>
    );
}


function Bottom(props) {
    const {visible} = props;
    const state = useRef(0);
   
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Hey', state.current++);
    });

    return (
        <>
            {visible && <div>BOTTOM</div> }
        </>
    );
}
```

Whenever we click on button MIDDLE,  mounts/unmounts successively; at least this is my understanding, since it is added/removed into/from the DOM. Hence, what I should expect is not to persist its state. Instead, what it does happen is that `state.current` always increases its value. I am really confused...

Comment: Compare what you have with `{ show && <Bottom visible={show} /> }` in Middle component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still when `visible` value is `false` your `Bottom` component is described in your component tree. so that component never get unmounted but what actually get unmounted is the `div` element.

However if you do,

```
function Middle() {
    const [show, setShow]=useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>setShow(v=>!v)}>MIDDLE</button>
            {show && <Bottom visible={show}/>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now your `Buttom` component get unmount when `show` false. This time your ref will be reset back to it's initial value as component get remounted freshly when `show` true.

Or if you are actually trying to reset your component you can use `key` prop. Just pass a different key value to your component when you need to reset your component.